# Forcing Certificate Auto-Reissue

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ad-certificate-services

Recently, I used AD Certificate Authority to automatically issue a remote desktop certificate to each client on the local domain. After the auto-issue, I realized that I failed to properly configure the root certificate's *CRL Distribution Point* property.

Now that I've set that property, is there a way to trigger an automatic re-issue/re-distribution of the client certificates so that they contain the updated CRL info?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Autoenrollment to automatically issue certificates, you can open Certificate Templates MMC snap-in, select desired template, right-click and select "Reenroll all certificate holders" option.